# Unit Testing NHibernate Repository

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nhibernate

I'm having some difficulty unit testing my NHibernate repository methods, basically due to the fact that they are being passed an expression and returning an IQueryable.

**Here's one of the repository methods:**

```
public TEntity FindBy<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
    return Session.Query<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(expression);
}
```

**And here's a related method call:**

```
public Employee Login(string username, string password)
{
    return Repository.FindBy<Employee>
    (
        e => e.Active 
            && e.Username.ToLower() == username.ToLower()
            && e.Password == password
    );
}
```

**And the associated unit test:**

```
[Test]
public void ForMatchingEmployeeUsernameAndPassword_ReturnsEmployee()
{       
    var employee = HelperEmployee.GetEmployee();

    repository.Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>())).Returns(employee);

    var result = EmployeeService.Login(employee.Username, employee.Password);

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Employee>(result);
    Assert.AreSame(employee, result);
}
```

And the test setup method:

```
[SetUp]
public void Init()
{
    mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    repository = mock.Object;
    EmployeeService = new EmployeeService(repository);
}
```

My problem arises when I try and mock the repository method, I'm passing the logic to it rather than executing the logic on the result it returns. So it's difficult to test my logic as I'm ignoring it and returning whatever I set in the mock.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? If I can provide more info let me know...

Comment: The `repository` instance doesn't appear to be injected into `EmployeeService`. How are you constructing `EmployeeService`?

Comment: Hi Jonathon, I'm injecting it in the test fixture SetUp method : EmployeeService = new EmployeeService(repository);

Comment: The first line of the test you've posted shows definition of `repository`. This happens after the `SetUp` method is called which means the mock is not used. Perhaps add in your `SetUp` method to the above.

Comment: Updated to include test setup method :)

Comment: Here is implementation of [mockable repository](http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/in-spite-of-common-now-approach-of.html) and nhibernate with some explanations.

Comment: Note sure if it's your problem but the repository method you've posted is not the same as the one you're mocking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7399/discussion-between-jonathan-and-timothyclifford)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've managed to get a working sample of what you're trying to do, using NUnit and RhinoMocks. All this test is doing is checking that `FindBy` is called, I think you'd need an integration test to cover that the correct filter expression is being applied.

**IRepository**

```
public interface IRepository
{
    TEntity FindBy<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);
}
```

**LoginService**

```
public class LoginService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public LoginService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Employee Login(string username, string password)
    {
        return _repository.FindBy<Employee>
        (
            e => e.Active
                && e.Username.ToLower() == username.ToLower()
                && e.Password == password
        );
    }
}
```

**LoginServiceTests**

```
[TestFixture]
class LoginServiceTests
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    private LoginService _loginService;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _repository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository>();
        _loginService = new LoginService(_repository);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Login_should_return_employee()
    {
        var expected = new Employee { Username = "Jon" };

        _repository.Expect(f => f.FindBy(Arg<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>.Is.Anything)).Return(expected);

        var result = _loginService.Login("jon", "mysecret");

        Assert.That(result, Is.InstanceOf<Employee>());
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for all your help mate, think i will was going slightly down wrong path trying to test repository methods rather than the logic :)